# Recursion Variable

Tags: c

I've just started with recursions and i wanted to pass a variable that is declared in a function to the main.

Here is the code to help you understand it a little bit better:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void InvertString(char string[200], char *inverted) {
  if (*string != '\0') {
    InvertString(string+1, inverted);
  }
  *inverted = *string;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  char string[200];
  char inverted;
  int i;
  printf("Give me a phrase: ");
  gets(string);
  printf("Tu frase invertida es: ");
  InviertString(string, &inverted);
  printf("%c", inverted); /* Here I'm tring to print "inverted", but i don't know how to pass that variable to the main */
  printf("\n");
}
```

Thank you for your help.

What about this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void InvierteFrase(char cadena[200]) {
  if (*cadena != '\0') {
    InvierteFrase(cadena+1);
  }
  printf("%c", *cadena);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  char cadena[200];
  char invertido[200];
  int i;
  printf("Dame una frase: ");
  gets(cadena);
  printf("Tu frase invertida es: ");
  InvierteFrase(cadena);
  printf("%c", &cadena);
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: [Don't use gets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used). use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: I don't see any variables declared in a function outside of main in this code.

Comment: `inverted` is not a variable. It's the name of a parameter. It's only visible inside the function that is receiving that parameter. It only exists from the point it's declared in `void InvertString()` to the closing brace of that function. Re-read your lessons.

Comment: Ok, so what i need to do then is pass that `inverted` to the main to print what it is giving me the `InvertString` function. How can i actually do that?

Comment: I feel you're probably asking the wrong question.  How do you expect main to print your inverted string when it is only printing a single character?

Comment: `printf("%c", &cadena);`->`printf("%s", cadena);`

Answer (score 0):

In `main` you declare a variable of type `char` called `inverted` - this can only hold one character. You then pass it as a pointer to your function and try to use it as a string which won't work.

Instead you could declare it as an array of char, much the same way you declare `string`

```
char inverted[200];
```

... and then change how you're calling the function and just pass in `inverted` since it is now a string.

```
InvertString(string, inverted);
```

You'd then print it as normal as a string

```
printf("%s", inverted);
```

Your recursive function doesn't work because you never change the value of `inverted`. What you probably want is for `inverted` to point at the end of where your reversed string would be and track backwards.

Something along the lines of:

```
void InvertString(char *string, char *inverted) {
  if (*string != '\0') {
    *inverted = *string;
    InvertString(string+1, inverted-1);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  char string[200];
  char inverted[200] = { 0 };
  int i;
  printf("Give me a phrase: ");
  fgets(string,200,stdin);
  printf("Tu frase invertida es: ");
  InvertString(string, inverted+strlen(string)-1);
  printf("%s", inverted); /* Here I'm tring to print "inverted", but i don't know how to pass that variable to the main */
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Ok, but when i do that, what happens is that if i put for example "hello", i only get the `h`, but i need to get `olleh` on the `printf`, how can i do that?

Comment: That's cos your recursive routine isn't right either...bit long for a comment, so I'll tack on what is wrong in the answer

Comment: I mean, the recursion does it's job when i do `printf("%s", invertido);` inside of it, it does print the word inverted. And i want to get the whole inverted word to the main and print it there.

Comment: Your function doesn't change the value of `inverted` though, so how would it ever change anything except for the first character?

Comment: I edited, the post, check it out. Now what i get is `olleh'` with that little `'`

Comment: That isn't reversing the string - it's just printing out the original string backwards

Comment: That's actually what i want. Get the original string printed backwards, store it in a variable and print that variable in the main.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void InvierteFrase(char cadena[200]) {
  if (*cadena != '\0') {
    InvierteFrase(cadena+1);
  }
  printf("%c", *cadena);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  char cadena[200];
  char invertido[200];
  int i;
  printf("Dame una frase: ");
  gets(cadena);
  printf("Tu frase invertida es: ");
  InvierteFrase(cadena);
  for(i=0;i>=strlen(cadena);i++){
  printf("%c", cadena[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: If you use this technique then what is the point of using recursing??? Just print the string in reverse order? Check this line `for(i=0;i>=strlen(cadena);i++)` properly. This loop will never execute.